# Path JobQueue cannot serialize String HashSet

Tags: java, android, priority-queue, job-queue

I need to serialize a collection of Strings for the JobQueue. How do I do that? Using `HashSet<String>` causes an exception. I am using https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue (there is no hashtag for it here)

```
error while serializing object PersistNotificationSettingsJob
 java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mycompanyandroid.Application
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.persistentQueue.sqlite.SqliteJobQueue$JavaSerializer.serialize(SqliteJobQueue.java:347)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.persistentQueue.sqlite.SqliteJobQueue.safeSerialize(SqliteJobQueue.java:324)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.persistentQueue.sqlite.SqliteJobQueue.getSerializeBaseJob(SqliteJobQueue.java:319)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.persistentQueue.sqlite.SqliteJobQueue.bindValues(SqliteJobQueue.java:75)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.persistentQueue.sqlite.SqliteJobQueue.insert(SqliteJobQueue.java:59)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.cachedQueue.CachedJobQueue.insert(CachedJobQueue.java:26)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobManager.addJob(JobManager.java:499)
     at com.path.android.jobqueue.JobManager$4.run(JobManager.java:565)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to serialize the Application class which is not serializable.
Make it transient and acquire from somewhere while your job is running. You can also obtain it from `job#getApplicationContext`.
http://yigit.github.io/android-priority-jobqueue/javadoc/index.html